# append Element based on option selection and conditions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, append

I am trying to create a function where the div will show based on the select box option selection and the selected option will disappear, again if the div is hidden then the select box option will appear.

e.g in my code When I select **Red** Option then the div#red show();

When I click **cancel('red')** the div is disappeared as expected by it the select option for red is still removed, I want to reflect the same.

how I achieve the goal, help

```
<select id="colorselector">
   <option value="0" selected>--</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none; color:red"> red... 
  <span><a onclick="cancel('red')">Cancel</a></span>
</div>

<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none; color:yellow"> yellow.. 
  <span><a onclick="cancel('yellow')">Cancel</a></span>
</div>

<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none; color:blue"> blue.. 
  <span><a onclick="cancel('')">Cancel</a></span>
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
  $('#colorselector').change(function() {
    $('.colors').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    $('option:selected').remove();
  });
});

function cancel(num) {
  $("div#" + num).remove();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here:
`When I click cancel('red') the div is disappeared as expected by it the select option for red is still removed, I want to reflect the same.`

Comment: @hamza765 select an option -> block is shown, option hidden - click "cancel" in that block -> block is hidden, option is restored

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks, but that still doesn't clear up what the intended functionality is. As in, what's happening right now and what should instead be happening?

Comment: @hamza765 you're right, I was too succinct.   Problem is that OP calls `.remove()` on the `option` and they want it back when they click cancel in the block.   ie toggle between `option` and `div` - problem is that they're calling `.remove()` and don't know how to get the HTML back (because it's gone).  They could add with `$("select").add("<option value=...` etc or use hide/show.

Comment: @freedomn-m ahhh, i understand now, thanks. And your answer is exactly what i was thinking, but didn't want to answer until the question was clear to me. Kudos!

Comment: @hamza765 yes, sometimes it's better to be clear, other times, just jump on in with an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `.remove()` *deletes* the html from the page - the only way to add it back would be to re-add the option (and the colour div).

Instead, use `.hide()` and `.show()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#colorselector').change(function() {
    $('.colors').hide();
    $("option").show();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    $('option:selected').hide();
  });
});

function cancel(num) {
  $("div#" + num).hide();
  $('option').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="colorselector">
   <option value="0" selected>--</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none; color:red"> red... 
  <span><a onclick="cancel('red')">Cancel</a></span>
</div>

<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none; color:yellow"> yellow.. 
  <span><a onclick="cancel('yellow')">Cancel</a></span>
</div>

<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none; color:blue"> blue.. 
  <span><a onclick="cancel('blue')">Cancel</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: but it working on only one selection, can I select a red, yellow, and blue option one by one, and show all div too based on selected options

Comment: When you re-show the `option` you need to tell it which one to reshow.  I just made it reshow all of them in the first instance.